# Why does Matlab's clear violates transparency?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, worker

while using Matlab `parfor` I came across the following behaviour

```
parpool(2)
parfor j=1:100
    v = j+1;
    clear v
end
> Error in ==> parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general at 886
> Transparency violation error.
```

I [looked into it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/transparency.html), and indeed one is not allowed to use `clear` within `parfor`.

**My question** is why. `v` is created inside every specific worker, and so it does not interfere with other workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab uses static code analyzer to understand how the body of parfor loop interacts with main workspace, i.e. which variables need to be transferred to workers and back. A number of functions, such as `eval`, `evalc`, `evalin`, `assignin` (with the workspace argument specified as `'caller'`), `load` (unless the output is assigned to a variable), `save` and `clear` can modify workspace in ways that cannot be predicted by the static analyzer. There is no way to ensure integrity of the workspace when multiple workers are operating on it, and such functions are used.

Important thing to realize is that when you use a command syntax to invoke a function, such as `clear v`, [the argument is passed as a **string literal**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html#zmw57dd0e809161), meaning there is no way for the static analyzer to understand which variable you are trying to clear, hence no way to figure out the effect the command will have on the workspace.

As suggested [in documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/transparency.html), the workaround to free up most of the memory used by a variable inside parfor is: `v = [];`